# Releasing code containing MIT library using all right reserved license?

Tags: mit, closed-source

For example, I have code

```
int main()
{
    myFunction();
    MitCopyPastedFunction();
}
```

where I have copied a section of code from a MIT licensed library. In this case, i want to release my project code with all right reserved.

1. is this allowed under MIT licensing of the library?
2. If it is allowed, I believe I would still need to include original MIT license notice due to

   *The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.*

in this case, how can I include this without having the included MIT license for library applying to my original code which is not intended to be MIT licensed?

Answer (score 2):

You must retain the notice and make it clear (at least by the name of the library) which code the MIT license terms apply to. You do **not** need to make the MIT license terms apply to the software as a whole. (If a license does require this, we call it a "copyleft" license. The MIT license is **not** a copyleft license.)

For example, here is a screenshot of how the Chrome browser (which is under a proprietary license) attributes the libraries it uses in `chrome://about`:

[image: screenshot of the page chrome://about showing permissive terms for Android Crazy Linker]

Comment: So a simple credits page would suffice? Am i correct in understanding I do not need to specify which part of code in particular is my own vs MIT licensed?

Comment: @gstcsr, that is correct.